# When running in a single process, does async make sense

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, architecture

In a MVC application I want to log some data on every single page request, and this requires a database call to insert the data into sql server.

Does it make sense to make this log operation asynchronous?

It doesn't make sense to me because this web application is running as a single process, so if performance is ever a problem it won't help if the log operation is done async because it will also effect the web application.

Am I wrong here?

Comment: You right, it make sense only if perfomance is not heavy problem. But anyway you always can put logs into other database than your operational.

Comment: @teovankot might point is even if performance is a problem, it won't help unless the asych call is to some other process i.e. another service

Comment: This is true statement from logic point of view - you've started with completely false assumption (async makes sense only when operation runs in multiple processes which is never the case for .Net code) and hence any conclusion will keep overall statement true.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov but the asych operation is making a blocking db call, so how does moving to asych help when in the same process?   Ofcourse you can have multiple processes i.e. another server or a 3rd party API you may be calling.

Comment: The purpose of asynchronous code using async await in asp.net is to release your thread. This means your thread is released to the thread pool and available for another request. Your application is maybe running in a single process but can handle multiple request concurrently with multiple threads from the threadpool. Async call's to the database or other i/o allows you server to handle more requests simultaneously. However the difference will only be noticed at high load (lot of requests / sec). Check https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2287

Comment: @JimmyH The thread handling the web request gets released, but a thread will also be used to respond to the async request.  You just passing the buck no?

Comment: @cool breeze consider you make a non async i/o call in your request handling that takes 25ms. This means the thread is blocked. During that time it cannot process other requests. This way you quickly end up using all the available threads in the pool. At that moment the scheduler will have to create new threads for new requests which is an expensive operation (time and memory wise). If you make your call async, the thread is released during the 25ms I/O operation and can handle other requests. After the I/O operation completes of course some thread will resume the handling of the request.

Comment: @JimmyH I understand that.  But explain to me how the async request will  execute?  It will also use a thread right?  I can see the website being more responsive, but given enough load it will still crash regardless.